# Scala: why it is possible to have Some(None)?

Tags: scala

```
>Option(None)
res2: Option[None.type] = Some(None)
```

Why it is possible? Why Option of None doesn't returns None?

Comment: You can have nested options has type `Option[Option[T]]`.

Comment: Yes, I can, but do I need?

Comment: @IvanZelenskyy there are situations where you might want to represent something using `Option[Option[A]]`. For example, object fields in JSON. A field can be missing, represented by `None`, or it can be present, but `null`, and you'd represent that using `Some(None)`, or it can have a value, represented using `Some(Some(value))`.

Comment: @IvanZelenskyy My answer is basically "at that level Scala doesn't care about what you need, and that's a good thing, because I don't want the Scala language designers trying to predict (and therefore limit) what I need".

Comment: You really wouldn't want Option to behave differently on what the type inside it was. Having the behavior always be the same regardless of the type inside makes Option's behavior both _simple_ and _predictable_. If it behaved differently when nested, both of those properties would be lost.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Scala (like most statically typed functional programming languages) is built out of pieces that can be composed together in consistent ways. This is in contrast with other programming languages and libraries (often dynamic ones) that attempt to predict the programmer's intentions and often support this by having lots of special cases (automatic flattening of nested constructions, etc.).

In Scala `Option` is just a type constructor—you can create an `Option[A]` for literally any type `A` by writing `Option(a)`. `Option[Int]` is itself a type, for example, so you could have an `Option[Option[Int]]`, an `Option[Option[Option[Int]]]`, and so on. There are no special cases, just a general mechanism for building up programs.

Comment: As a footnote, the most painful parts of Scala (implicit conversions, etc.) are almost all attempts to bolt on the more special-case-y feel you get in dynamic languages.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is a good answer. But try read next article.

http://danielwestheide.com/blog/2012/12/19/the-neophytes-guide-to-scala-part-5-the-option-type.html

Some is actually a wrapper for the value you trying to use. So your code is valid.